# why does $\sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)}P(X_2=l)E(X_1|X_2=l)=\sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)}P(X_2)\sum\limits_{k\in X_1(\Omega_1)}kP(X_1=k|X_2=l)$?

Tags: probability

I have to show that $E(E(X_1|X_2))=E(X1)$.

A friend of mine gave me this clue:
$\sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)}P(X_2=l)E(X_1|X_2=l)=\sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)}P(X_2)\sum\limits_{k\in X_1(\Omega_1)}kP(X_1=k|X_2=l)$

Yet I don't understand how does it appears. How do we find the first member and how is it equal to the second one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $Y:=E(X_1\mid X_2)$ is *by definition*  a random variable that satisfies $\mathbb EY1_A=\mathbb EX_11_A$ for each $A\in\sigma(X_2)$. Applying that on $A=\Omega$ gives exactly what you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:  $\mathsf E(g(X_2)) = \sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)} g(l)\;\mathsf P(X_2=l)$

So where $g(X_2) = \mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2)$ , then $g(l)=\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2=l)$, so:

$$\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2)) = \sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)}\;\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2=l)\mathsf P(X_2=l)$$

---

By definition $\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2=l) = \sum\limits_{k\in X_1(\Omega_1)} k\;\mathsf P(X_1=k\mid X_2=l)$

---

Putting it together:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2)) 
 & = \sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)} \mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2=l)\;\mathsf P(X_2=l)
\\[1ex] & = \sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)} \sum\limits_{k\in X_1(\Omega_1)} k\;\mathsf P(X_1=k\mid X_2=l)\;\mathsf P(X_2=l)
\\[1ex] & = \sum\limits_{l\in X_2(\Omega_2)} \sum\limits_{k\in X_1(\Omega_1)} k\;\mathsf P(X_1=k, X_2=l)
\\[1ex] & = ...
\end{align}$$